# How do I list all table names that are related to a specific table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

How do I list all table names that are related (through foreign key) to a specific table.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.table_name FROM a WHERE a.foreign_key_rel = 'specific_table_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up this kind of information in the [system catalogs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalogs.html), in this case `pg_constraint`:

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE confrelid = 'specific_table_name'::regclass
  AND contype = 'f';
```

Comment: Absolutely helpful! Thank you.